# Увеличение id записей

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Прошу прощения, я не знаю, как правильно выразиться, поэтому описываю простыми словами, чего хочу.

Допустим, в базе есть таблица формата

```
[число ID] [текст Имя] [текст Фамилия]
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при добавлении новой записи ID увеличивался на 1

То есть, допустим, записи в таблице

```
[id = 0] [Имя = Алексей] [Фамилия = Неназванный]
[id = 1] [Имя = Евгений] [Фамилия = Названный]
[id = 2] [Имя = Фёдор]   [Фамилия = Неизвестный]
```

И я хочу, чтобы при добавлении новой записи, в поле `Id` добавилось число +1 от предыдущей записи

Как покороче сформировать запрос на добавление записи?

С уважением

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При создании таблицы просто необходимо было использовать спецификатор AUTOINCREMENT. В таком случае id будет генерироваться автоматически.

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (
 id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 fisrt_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 last_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Для того чтоб добавить запись в таблицу, сформированную в запросе выше (она аналогична той что в вопросе) необходимо выполнить такой запрос:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (first_name, last_name) VALUES('Имя','Фамилия');
```

При этом id новой записи будет сгенерирован самой СУБД и равен *id предыдущей записи +1*

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: а как автоматично сгенерировать последующие id скажем на +5 или +20? IDENTITY(1,56) - не работает